# Why is Captain America disappointed with SHIELD?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, when Stark is about to bring The Vision to life over Captain America's objection, Captain America says that "the Avengers were supposed to be different than SHIELD.".

Then later when Sokovia is flying and the SHIELD helicarrier appears, Pietro says " this is SHIELD?" And Captain America replies "this is what SHIELD is supposed to be.".

**Why is Captain America disappointed with SHIELD?**

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't seen _Captain America: The Winter Soldier_.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Because SHIELD turned out to be a militarized police force

> which neo-nazi Hydra corrupted from the inside (*Captain America: The Winter Soldier*),

using SHIELD to create weapons of mass destruction (*The Avengers/Avengers Assemble*: Steve Rogers finds weapons based on Tesseract) and planned on

> killing people for potentially being dangerous to the new world order (*Captain America: The Winter Soldier*).

At the end of *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, Fury's SHIELD acted as peace keepers and rescuers, saving people, not policing them.

Comment: Avengers, Captain America- Winter Soldier, Age of Ultron.

Comment: don't forget the Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.

Comment: This is basically the core point of the whole Insight plotline in *Winter Soldier*, and a key part of the "you create your own demons" plotline in *Age Of Ultron*.

Comment: It's basically Cap's entire bloody story arc in the whole MCU.

Comment: @Petersaber im not sure Capt has any ties to Agents, he's movies only at this time.

Comment: @cde: No, but he has ties to S.H.I.E.L.D., and _Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D._ shows us much about what that organisation gets up to. There is evidence in there about why a character such as Rogers may be disappointed with the organisation.

Comment: @cde what I meant is that Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. shows us some things that disappointed Cap. After all, the show and the movies are intertwined to some degree.